# Changing VPS provider, kernels changed...broke my iptables how do I fix it?

Tags: centos, iptables, kernel

Hi guys I am changing host providers and I was running centOS 5.7 on my machine with the kernel 2.6.18-274.el5

On my new vps the kernel is 2.6.32.12 and the OS is centOS 5.6...they did not have 5.7

When I use this my old iptables no longer work...does anyone know how to fix it?

This is my current iptables config

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Sun Jan  1 13:39:33 2012
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [129:44518]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p ah -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -d 224.0.0.251 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 843 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 646 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 7777 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 10009 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 7778 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25566 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8765 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8192 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8123 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 9987 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9091 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 51413 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 10011 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 30033 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jan  1 13:39:33 2012
```

Comment: Also what steps have you taken, what error(s) are you getting, and what is the output of `iptables -nvL`?

Answer (score 1):

You can update any version of CentOS 5.x to the latest version (in this case, CentOS 5.7). A provider I used to use only offered 5.2, but I updated to 5.7 just fine after the initial installation.

Give `yum clean all && yum update` a try (clean all just tidies up your packages a bit and resolves common errors). Once you've done that, try `cat /etc/redhat-release` and you should get `CentOS release 5.7 (Final)`.

As for your question, the only difference I can think of is iptables version (yum update will fix that), or your backup uses venet0 (OpenVZ) and your new interface is eth0 (Xen) for example?

Comment: My old server was a dedicated my new one is an xen server

Comment: What do you get from `ifconfig` ? `iptables -v` may also be useful.

Comment: I get this http://pastebin.com/tdSnTCeu

Comment: Then it probably isn't an interface issue. Can you elaborate on iptables "not working" at all? Error messages or log entries would be great.

Comment: Applying iptables firewall rules: iptables-restore v1.3.5: iptables-restore: unable to initializetable 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 2

Is the error.

Comment: That error is generated when there's a problem with the netfilter module (it's used to hook the kernel). I would do the `yum update`, and see if it works once the kernel is updated. If not, the only thing I can think of right now would be building the kernel from source, as that should at least give you the option to make sure netfilter is compiled in with the other modules.

Comment: I did yum update. Still the same issue.

Comment: Was the kernel updated as part of that update? Are you now seeing 5.7 when you do `cat /etc/redhat-release`? If it was updated, have you restarted?

Comment: I am seeing 5.7 when I do that. Kernel is still the same.

Comment: Do you happen to know where the kernel came from? My 5.7 server installation is fully updated as of about a minute ago, but it is only using kernel `2.6.18-274.18.1.el5`. My 6.2 server install is using a kernel version more similar to yours (`2.6.32-220.4.2.el6.x86_64`). Can you provide the full output of `uname -r` ?

Comment: 2.6.32.12-mammoth1, my host provides a few to choose from. But they don't go as low as my old server.

Comment: mammothvps.com.au? They seem to be compiling a newer kernel than the one shipping with CentOS 5.7. If I had to guess, I'd say the kernel they have compiled doesn't include the netfilter module - if I got the host right (let me know, if you would), then it'd probably be best to drop support a ticket/email - their knowledgebase doesn't really contain much useful information (at a quick glance, anyway).

Comment: Yep, they are using a newer kernel...is their a way to go down easily?

Comment: [This](http://www.mammothvps.com.au/kb/troubleshooting/custom-kernels) is the only page I can find related to their custom kernel stuff. You could probably do a `yum install kernel` to put the one from the CentOS repository on there, but based on that KB article, I don't know if that would break it or not - if you try it, have a backup and be prepared to reinstall. I would contact support, tell them you want to downgrade to a CentOS kernel (not one of their builds), and asking them how to do it. The alternative is building from source yourself, and making sure the netfilter module is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it matters or not, but I count several duplicate lines in your iptables for port 80:

`-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

Try to remove them and see if it fixes it.

There's also several trailing spaces in your pasted rules, you should clean that out. also make sure there are no ^M characters (Windows carriage returns).

Here's a cleaned output. I also ordered the rules by port so it's easier to read:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Sun Jan  1 13:39:33 2012
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [129:44518]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p ah -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -d 224.0.0.251 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 10009 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 10011 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25566 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 30033 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 51413 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 646 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 7777 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 7778 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8123 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8192 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 843 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8765 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9091 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 9987 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jan  1 13:39:33 2012
```